# Android Api 29: Launcher Activity not getting extra data when FCM notification is clicked

Tags: android

With api 29, I am trying to open "**DesiredActivity**" when a notification is **tapped**.

But my "**LauncherActivity**" is **not** getting any **extra data** which contains information about which activity to launch and its content.

My implementation for below api 26 works as expected.

I followed this article for api 29 (Android Oreo Simulator):

https://medium.com/@mountainappstudio/open-specific-activity-when-notification-clicked-in-fcm-android-app-development-f1c1d9a75fb5

Why is LauncherActivity not getting extra data?

My FCM notification looks like:

```
{
  "to":"your_device_token",
  "data": {
      "title": "hello",
      "message": "test message",
  },
 "priority":"high"
}
```

I write extras in FcmListenerService:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), LauncherActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_INTENT_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE, notif_type);
```

I read extras in LaunchActivity:

```
    String notification_type = getIntent().
         getStringExtra(KEY_INTENT_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE);
```

Comment: Could you please share how do you add/retrieve the extras from the bundle?

Comment: @W0rmH0le String notification_type = getIntent().
         getStringExtra(KEY_INTENT_EXTRA_NOTIFICATION_TYPE);